# Why won't my code delete the specific element in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

So to learn c# I have been creating a program that diplays stuff I need to renember and give me the ability to change and delete those. I've gotten to the stage of making a button that deletes a the xml element from a file based on where it is. The problem is that only the first button deletes anything and it deletes everything. I was wondering what I did wrong. Can anyone help please?

Sorry that it's messy.

```
String Buttonname = (sender as Button).Name;
int RowCount = Int16.Parse(Buttonname.Remove(0, 9));

string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string dataPath = Path.Combine(appDataPath, "Remembrall 2.0");
string EventslistFullPath = Path.Combine(dataPath, "Events.xml");

Label Labelname = (Label)this.Controls.Find("DetailsLbl"+RowCount, true)[0];
string Detailtext = Labelname.Text;
//gets the text from a dynamicaly generated textbox

MessageBox.Show (Detailtext);

for (int z = 0; z < Table.ColumnCount; z++)
{
    Control con = Table.GetControlFromPosition(z, RowCount);
    Table.Controls.Remove(con);
    con.Dispose();
}

XDocument EventDoc = XDocument.Load(EventslistFullPath);

label1.Text = Detailtext;

EventDoc.Descendants("Events").Where(ele => ele.Element("Event").Value == Detailtext).Remove();
//Deletes the element based off the value of the text.


EventDoc.Save(EventslistFullPath);
```

Comment: can you share you xml file, will help us to identify the structure of you xml? i think you can use just ``EventDoc.Descendants("Event")....``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```cs
EventDoc.Descendants("Events").Where(ele => ele.Element("Event").Value == Detailtext).Remove();
```

says "find all `<Events>` nodes under the event doc; for each, see if the first `<Event>` node in there matches `Detailtext`; if it does, remove that `<Events>`". You *probably* meant:

```cs
EventDoc.Descendants("Events").Elements("Event").Where(evt => evt.Value == Detailtext).Remove();
```

which says "find all `<Events>` nodes, and for each find all the `<Event>` nodes under it; remove any of those `<Event>` that match `Detailtext`".

Note that this still means that duplicates get a little dicey, i.e. if multiple nodes have the value `"abc"`, clicking delete on any one of the `"abc"` will remove *all* of them..

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. grasping how this worked has been difficult. Now to deal with other errors.

Also to the person who commented on my question. Sorry didnt mean to delete it.